# Why can't gcc reduce the alignment of a struct to be lesser than that of one of its individual fields

Tags: c, memory, struct, memory-alignment

I have a struct definition `employee` that instantiates `monica`. The struct looks like this

```c
struct __attribute__((aligned(2))) employee {
    int salary; // 4 bytes
    int age; // 4 bytes
} monica;
```

As you can see, I have forced the alignment of the struct to be `2` but gcc does not set the alignment of the struct to 2, nor does it throw an error. I tried to print the alignment of the struct using the `alignof` macro(include `<stdalign.h>`) which returns `4` as the alignment of the struct. Why can't gcc set the alignment of a struct to value that is less than the largest alignment of one of its fields.

I tried to reproduce the issue by additionally adding a pointer as a field in the struct. On adding the pointer as a field, I noticed that gcc does not allow me to reduce the alignment below 8 using `__attribute__((aligned(x)))`.

GCC allows me to set the alignment of the struct to `1` by using `__attribute__((packed))` but it still does not allow me to set the alignment to `1` by using `__attribute__((aligned(1)))`. Why is this happening?

gcc x86 v7.1.1

Comment: What difference you expect between `aligned(1)` and `packed`? `packed` means that no blank bytes will be inserted between members.

Comment: @i486 I do not expect any difference between the both. I wanted to point out that gcc does not set the alignment of the struct as `1` when using `aligned(1)`, but it does set the alignment of the struct as `1` when using `packed`.

Comment: How you test the effect of `aligned(1)`? The best way is to printf `sizeof (monica)` in both cases (with and without alignment). But replace `salary` (first member) with type `char` for better effect. Now with `int` you may get the same result with any `alignment` and `packed`.

Comment: @i486 As I mentioned in the question, I test the alignment of the struct using the `alignof` macro which is included in `<stdalign.h>`.

Comment: I do not understand what you expect from `alignof`. Its result has no relation to structure definition (with `aligned` or `packed`). As I wrote above - see the total size of structure with `sizeof (monica)` and different types of alignment.

Comment: `alignof`'s result has a relation to the structure alignment which is defined by `aligned` or `packed`. Using the method you mentioned, the alignment still cannot be reduced to anything less than 4(size of the largest field of the struct) except by the method Eric Postpischil mentioned in an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes) says:

> … When used on a struct, or struct member, the `aligned` attribute can only increase the alignment; in order to decrease it, the `packed` attribute must be specified as well…

That is from the GCC 11.2 documentation. You can check older documentation. There is none for 7.1 at that site; it jumps from 6.5 to 7.5, but I expect it is the same in this regard.